# Use of nlog.xml

Tags: nlog

I just started playing with nlog, and noticed that nlog.xml file is brought along with nlog.dll into the output folder of the application. It's not too clear for me what that file is needed for and whether i should carry it over as a part of my app install or can safely remove it. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Andrey

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can remove it from the output. The XML file contains the nlog data for the intellisense.