# how to disable generate a NLog.xml file while build c# solutions?

Tags: c#, nlog

every time i click build solution, a file named NLog.xml occur on the Debug or Release folder.
it has no use in production actually, and it uses 1.6Mb, so how can i disable generate it whild build solution?

Comment: Not sure how you can avoid that it is generated, but you don't need the file. When you move your program to production, don't copy the Nlog.xml file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of nlog.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209704/use-of-nlog-xml)

Comment: Is it a nlog.xml or nlog.config (xml content). What's the content of the nlog.xml?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011434/preventing-referenced-assembly-pdb-and-xml-files-copied-to-output ?